# Flutter w/ Google Cloud Datastore Implementation

Tags: google-app-engine, flutter, dart, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore

I'm trying to connect my Flutter project to my Google cloud datastore. I've been trying to make use of the logic from here https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis#-example-tab-.

So far I have got the below:

```
    String jsonCredentials = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
    final _credentials = new ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(json.decode(jsonCredentials));

    const _SCOPES = const [ds.DatastoreApi.DatastoreScope];

    auth.clientViaServiceAccount(_credentials, _SCOPES).then((http_client) {
      var datastore = new ds.DatastoreApi(http_client);
    });
```

The above just lets me connect to the API, however I've been reading through the documentation on that site and I'm not sure how I can then proceed to read in the data from my datastore. Can anyone provide any examples of this please?

Comment: I absolutely don't know flutter. But AFAIK, it's a client framework (like Angular and Vue). If so, I understand that the `data.json` is a service account key file and it's in plain text on client side. If I'm still correct, you don't have to do this! Your secret is no longer secret!!

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to do this using google cloud plugin for flutter.

here is the link

https://pub.dev/packages/gcloud

Getting access to the APIs
The first step in using the APIs is to get an authenticated HTTP client and with that create API class instances for accessing the different APIs. The code below assumes that you have a Google Cloud Project called my-project with credentials for a service account from that project stored in the file my-project.json.

// Read the service account credentials from the file.

```
var jsonCredentials = new File('my-project.json').readAsStringSync();
var credentials = new auth.ServiceAccountCredentials.fromJson(jsonCredentials);

// Get an HTTP authenticated client using the service account credentials.
var scopes = []
    ..addAll(datastore_impl.DatastoreImpl.SCOPES)
    ..addAll(Storage.SCOPES)
    ..addAll(PubSub.SCOPES);
var client = await auth.clientViaServiceAccount(credentials, scopes);

// Instantiate objects to access Cloud Datastore, Cloud Storage
// and Cloud Pub/Sub APIs.
var db = new DatastoreDB(
    new datastore_impl.DatastoreImpl(client, 's~my-project'));
var storage = new Storage(client, 'my-project');
var pubsub = new PubSub(client, 'my-project');
All the APIs in this package supports the use of 'service scopes'. Service scopes are described in details below.

ss.fork(() {
  // register the services in the new service scope.
  registerDbService(db);
  registerStorageService(storage);
  registerPubSubService(pubsub);

  // Run application using these services.
});
```

Reading and Writing

```
var person = new Person()
..name = ''
..age = 42;
```

await db.commit(inserts: [person]);
The function query is used to build a Query object which can be run to perform the query.

```
var persons = (await db.query<Person>().run()).toList();
To fetch one or multiple existing entities, use lookup.

var key = new Person()
    ..name = 'UniqueName'
    ..age = 42
    ..parentKey = db.emptyKey;
var person = (await db.lookup<Person>([key])).single;
var people = await db.lookup<Person>([key1, key2]);
```

Comment: what are the values that have to be in my-project.json file, can u explain?