# How to access google cloud data store from flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datastore, flutter-dependencies

I have google cloud datastore(Cloud Firestore in Datastore mode),where i am putting my data from my IoT device. I need to access that data in my flutter app
how i can do that ?

Comment: Maybe you'd found the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61426851/flutter-w-google-cloud-datastore-implementation) yo be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to avoid using a server layer of cloud functions then:

Checkout this official library from Google: https://pub.dev/packages/googleapis